# How to share current state of map which is drawn by react-native-maps to google.com/maps?

Tags: react-native, maps

It's easy to share the current location by the link. For example: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kawameeh+Park/@40.6908352,-74.2648218,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c3ad7432e5ac57:0x5cbcead2beefaff!8m2!3d40.6908312!4d-74.2626331

Is there anyway to share a map with a polygon by the similar way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keene.edu is a good site to share a polygon in google maps.

For examples:
https://www.keene.edu/campus/maps/tool/?coordinates=-80.1576430%2C%2025.7364470%0A-73.3648160%2C%2019.0502020%0A-70.9999440%2C%2025.0003470%0A-80.1576430%2C%2025.7364470

So I have to write some lines of code to generate a url and use Linking to open that url